# Error: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Here's the error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len().
```

The code is:

```
from scipy.stats import randint as sp_randint
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
param_dist = {"max_depth":sp_randint(2,5),
              "learning_rate":random.uniform(0,0.2),
              "n_estimators":sp_randint(200,350),
              "min_child_weight":sp_randint(2, 8),
              "gamma":random.uniform(0,4),
              "subsample":random.uniform(0.7,0.3),
              "colsample_bytree":random.uniform(0.7,0.3),
              "reg_alpha":random.uniform(100,300),
              "reg_lambda":random.uniform(100,300)}

model_rs_xgb = RandomizedSearchCV(xgb.XGBClassifier(n_jobs=-1,random_state=25), param_distributions=param_dist,
                                   n_iter=30,scoring='neg_log_loss',cv=5,n_jobs=-1)
model_rs_xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)
pickle.dump(model_rs_xgb,open('model_rs_xgb.p','wb'))
```

Comment: What is the full traceback of the error?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in __iter__(self)
    279                         params[k] = v.rvs(random_state=rnd)
    280                     else:
--> 281                         params[k] = v[rnd.randint(len(v))]
    282                 yield params
    283

Comment: Please do *not* post code or error messages in the comments  - they are literally unreadable. Edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a problem with your training set.

Please check your training set if there any None value or any floating-point number.

for null remove from entire Dataframe use

```py
     df = df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

for checking any integer or floating-point value on your Dataframe (training set)use:

```
   df['traing_body'].str.len()
```

The model wants to receive string but it receives a float value.

Comment: what exactly should i check in the dataset? @Tarequzzaman Khan

Comment: Actually the model gives this error when it wants string as his feature but it receives float/ integer.  Can you pls share some sample of your data?

Comment: Also, check any null values on your training set

Comment: it has 6 fields id,qid1,qid2,question1,question2,is_duplicate and i am trying to solve quora qestion pairs competiton from kaggle. we have to predict if 2 questions are similar or not

Comment: Can you remove all the numbers from your  question1, question2? 


df['question1'].str.len()
df['question2'].str.len()

check is there any error occurs